# Calling a double from within a class

Tags: c#

Hello,

I'm trying to call the double paying from within the class "Wallet"
but when i try to do this it gives this error:

```
Member'Mc_DOnalds.Program.Paying' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.
```

This is in the class Wallet.

```
class Wallet
{
    public double WalletCustomer = 100;

    Program Betalen = new Program();
    public void Pay()
    {
        WalletCustomer = (WalletCustomer - Betalen.Paying);            
    }
  }
}
```

This is in the Program.cs

```
 public static double Paying = 0;
```

Comment: Hey Tim, you might want to read up on your coding conventions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx

Comment: Alright ill do that thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Paying` is static, you don't need to create an instance of the class to access the property. Try this (take a look on how I access the `Program.Paying`):

```
class Wallet
{
    public double WalletCustomer = 100;

    public void Pay()
    {
        WalletCustomer = (WalletCustomer - Program.Paying);            
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For `static` member you need to use `class` name instead of `instance`

```
WalletCustomer = (WalletCustomer - Program.Paying);
```

> You access the members of a static class by using the class name
>   itself. For example, if you have a static class that is named
>   UtilityClass that has a public method named MethodA, you call the
>   method as give below, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx).

```
UtilityClass.MethodA();
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is coming because you are trying to access your non static member from static class.
Solution: Either mark your member as static or change your Calling function to Non-Static.
or access your Non-Static Member with Class Name
 Here is how?

```
class Wallet
{
    public static double WalletCustomer = 100;

    Program Betalen = new Program();
    public void Pay()
    {
       WalletCustomer = (WalletCustomer - Betalen.Paying);            
    }
}
```

Or

```
class Wallet
{
     public double WalletCustomer = 100;

     Program Betalen = new Program();
     public void Pay()
     {
        WalletCustomer = (WalletCustomer - Betalen.Paying);            
     }
}
```

In your Main Program

```
Program.Paying = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [LeakyCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33708/leakycode), in C#, unlike VB.NET and Java, you can't access static members with instance syntax. You should do:

```
MyClass.MyItem.Property1
```

To refer to that property or remove the static modifier from `Property1` (which is what you probably want to do). For a conceptual idea about what static is, see my other answer.

Poom